# For loop execution understanding

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a question regarding for loop working

```
m=10
for i in range(0,m):
    m=m-1
    print(i)
```

The ouput is :0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Why it is not 0,1,2,3,4
because we are updating m value by m-1

Comment: Because the `range` has already been created with the original value of `m`.

Comment: range() gets evaluated once before the loop starts.

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant  tags to your question.

Comment: as for as for loop working is concerned it for first initialize the variable (let say i variable)then check condition if condition is true it executes for loop body then increment (variable i ) and again check condition.and here condition value is changing every time.

Comment: is for this  loop works different than for loop in java or c?

Comment: Yes, this for-loop is different from the ones that work differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a bit more detailed answer.

So first of all such problems starts when you start implementing Java, C# etc concepts in Python. It should be noted that Python is similar to other languages in some aspects and different in others.

`For-loop` of python is not same as java's. In java for loop is evaluated for the testing condition at each iteration, so when you increment or decrement a variable that is being used in loop evaluation condition, it affects the loop. For example:

```java
int m=10;
for (int i = 0; i <= m; i = i + 1) { // on each iteration it is checked that `i` is less than or equal to `m`
   m = m-1;
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

So here your loop wont' run from i=0 to i=11, as you are decrementing `m`. You can visualize it some like this:

```
╔════════════╦═══╦════╦══════════════╗
║ Iteration# ║ i ║ m  ║  Loop Test   ║
╠════════════╬═══╬════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║ 0 ║ 10 ║ 0<=10 : True ║
║          2 ║ 1 ║  9 ║ 1<=9 : True  ║
║          3 ║ 2 ║  8 ║ 2<=8 : True  ║
║          4 ║ 3 ║  7 ║ 3<=7 : True  ║
║          5 ║ 4 ║  6 ║ 4<=6 : True  ║
║          6 ║ 5 ║  5 ║ 5<=5 : True  ║
║          7 ║ 6 ║  4 ║ 6<=4 : False ║
╚════════════╩═══╩════╩══════════════╝
```

On each iteration `i` gets printed and on 7th loop test the condition gets false thus loop breaks.

Now come to Python(the great), you check into [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). You would think that if you do something like this: `print(range(4))`

You should will get this: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

But actually you will get this: `range(0, 4)`

This is where you have to be pythonic. Once you tell it to start at 0 and stop at `m` it will return a **reference to a generator object**. So instead of creating a list object and populate the whole list with values (which is is very memory inefficient when it comes to large ranges), python will do **lazy evaluation** and will calculate the number on each iteration. So it doesn't matter if you change the value of `m`, the `generator` has already being created once the for-loop started.

However, the behavior of Java's `for-loop` can be implemented using `while-loop` in python.

Answer (score 0):

That's because python `int`s are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types), meaning out cannot change the value of one.

Hence, you did not change the value of the previous variable, you simply created *another* variable that is also named `m`, also overwriting the previous one in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The number of times a `for` loop will run for, is already evaluated at the `for` loop itself, and the code after the `for` loop can't affect how many times it runs. It is fixed, until it is changed before the `for` loop runs, an error occurs, or a `break` is found within it.

Comment: public static void main(String []args){
         int m=10;
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i = i + 1) {
            m=m-1;
       System.out.println(i);
}0
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: you can check the the above code which is written in java and it is affecting the for loop execution

Comment: i was talking about python, this is how it works in python, its different in java and c++ because the for loop is like a while loop

Answer (score 0):

The `range` type represents an immutable sequence of numbers. means once a range object is created like `range(a,b) -> (a, a+1, a+2,...b)` then if you do change the value of limits(start or end) it won't affect the `for` statement.

so if you want to change the for loop execution, you need iterator which produces a mutable instance.